# ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1: invalid ELF header

Tags: python, dockerfile, fastapi

I am getting error while executing line  **RUN pip install poetry==1.1.13**  in following DockerFile (doing **dev up** in python (FastApi project)):

**DockerFile**

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /src
EXPOSE 8080

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl make && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip install poetry==1.1.13
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false
COPY poetry.lock /src/
COPY pyproject.toml /src/
RUN poetry export -f requirements.txt --without-hashes --output requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /src
RUN cd /src && python setup.py develop

RUN chmod +x /src/bin/run.sh

CMD ["/src/bin/run.sh"]
```

**Error**

> ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1: invalid ELF header

**Error Logs**

```
# ERROR
#8 1.550 Traceback (most recent call last):
#8 1.550   File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 8, in <module>
#8 1.550     sys.exit(main())
#8 1.550   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 68, in main
#8 1.550     command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
#8 1.550   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 114, in create_command
#8 1.550     module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
#8 1.550   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
#8 1.550     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
#8 1.550   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
#8 1.550   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
#8 1.551   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
#8 1.551   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
#8 1.551   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
#8 1.551   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
#8 1.551   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 16, in <module>
#8 1.551     from pip._internal.cli.req_command import (
#8 1.551   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 21, in <module>
#8 1.551     from pip._internal.index.package_finder import PackageFinder
#8 1.551   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 33, in <module>
#8 1.551     from pip._internal.req import InstallRequirement
#8 1.551   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
#8 1.551     from .req_install import InstallRequirement
#8 1.551   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 44, in <module>
#8 1.551     from pip._internal.operations.install.wheel import install_wheel
#8 1.551   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/install/wheel.py", line 39, in <module>
#8 1.551     from pip._vendor.distlib.scripts import ScriptMaker
#8 1.551   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 16, in <module>
#8 1.552     from .compat import sysconfig, detect_encoding, ZipFile
#8 1.552   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 83, in <module>
#8 1.552     import xmlrpc.client as xmlrpclib
#8 1.552   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/xmlrpc/client.py", line 138, in <module>
#8 1.552     from xml.parsers import expat
#8 1.552   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/xml/parsers/expat.py", line 4, in <module>
#8 1.552     from pyexpat import *
#8 1.552 ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1: invalid ELF header
#8 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install poetry==1.1.13]: exit code: 1
------
 > [ 4/12] RUN pip install poetry==1.1.13:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install poetry==1.1.13]: exit code: 1
Cleaning up...
 - No resources found
build failed: exit status 1. Docker build ran into internal error. Please retry
```

Comment: Possibly relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266973/python-application-crash-with-error-importerror-pyexpat-x86-64-linux-gnu-so-u